# Relation data table to Flat Data Table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, export-to-csv

```
Table Fan
-----------------------
| FanId | Name | Info |
-----------------------
| 17111 | Fan1 | Info1|
-----------------------  
| 17112 | Fan2 | Info2|
-----------------------
1:m
Table ProfileFan
----------------------------------
| Id | LinkedInProfileId | FanId |
----------------------------------
| 1111    | 1          | 17111   |
----------------------------------
| 1112    | 2          | 17111   |
----------------------------------
| 1113    | 1          | 17112   |
----------------------------------
| 1114    | 2          | 17112   |
----------------------------------
m:1
Table LinkedInProfile
--------------------------
| LiId | Name | Client    |
--------------------------
| 1    | Linked1 | Client1|
--------------------------
| 2    | Linked2 | Client1 |
--------------------------
```

What I need is the data from these relations Tables to be exported to CSV. So I am making a procedure to to the job and schedule it to run every hour.

The catch is that I need to insert the data from a query for one fan in a single row.

```
ExportToCsv Table
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| FanName | FanInfo  | LinkedInProfile1| LinkedInProfile2 | Client |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Fan1    | FanInfo1 | Linked1(1111)   |  Linked2(1112)  | Client1 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Fan2    | FanInfo2 | Linked1(1113)   |  Linked2(1114)  | Client1 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far my query is generating me rows for every ProfileFanId.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @ProfileFanId INT
SET @ProfileFanId=0
SELECT TOP (1)  @ProfileFanId =[dbo].[ExportCSV].ProfileFanId
    FROM [dbo].[ExportCSV] Order by ProfileFanId desc

IF @StatementType = 'Insert' 

INSERT INTO ExportCSV (FanId, SNUrl, FullName, FirstName, LastName, Company, JobTitle, [ExperienceDescription], [FANProfileLocation], [CompanyDescription], [CompanyIndustry], [CompanyLocationCity],
[CompanyLocationCountry], [NumberOfEmployees], [CompanySpecialities], [CompanyLiURL], [CompanyDomain], [TwitterHandles], [EMailAddress] ,[TelephoneNumber], ClientName1, CreatedAt, ProfileFanId )


SELECT DISTINCT B.LinkedInProfile ,B.SNUrl ,B.FullName, B.FirstName, B.LastName,B.Organization1,B.JobTitle,B.ExperienceDescr,B.ProfileLocation,B.OrganizationDescription1,B.Organization1Industry,
B.OrganizationCity1,B.OrganizationCountry1,B.Organization1Size, B.OrganizationSpecialities1, B.OrganizationLIID1,B.OrganizationDomain1, B.Twitter, B.Email, B.Phone, C.Name, SYSDATETIME(), A.Id, B.Id --,c.EmailResponseStatusId,c.FanStatusId,c.BatchId, n.DeliveryActionId, n.LoggedAt, f.ActivityId,f.Created
FROM ProfileFan A 
INNER JOIN Fan B ON A.FanId = B.Id
INNER JOIN LinkedInProfile C ON A.ProfileId = C.Id
--INNER JOIN Batch D ON A.BatchId = D.Id
where A.Id>@ProfileFanId

--------------------------------------------------------------------
| FanName | FanInfo  | LinkedInProfile1| LinkedInProfile2 | Client |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Fan1    | FanInfo1 | Linked1(1111)   |                  | Client1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Fan1    | FanInfo1 | Linked2(1112)   |                  | Client1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Fan2    | FanInfo2 | Linked1(1113)   |                  | Client1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Fan2    | FanInfo2 | Linked2(1114)   |                  | Client1|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea how to get the desired output is welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many of these `LinkedInProfileN` can you have for a single Fan record? If you have 10000 for a single Fan, you want to have 10000 columns in the CSV file?

Comment: 1 Fan can have many ProfileFans determined by LinkedInProfiles which are many. ex 2 profileFans are generated for 2 LinkedInProfiles, but have only 1 record in Fan Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use PIVOT with dynamic columns here.

Have a look at this for getting familiarised with dynamic PIVOT: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

I have simulated your example in the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE Fan(FanId int, Name varchar(100), Info varchar(100));

INSERT INTO Fan VALUES (17111,'Fan1','Info1'),(17112,'Fan2','Info2');

CREATE TABLE LinkedInProfile(LiId int, Name varchar(100), Client varchar(100));

INSERT INTO LinkedInProfile VALUES (1,'Linked1','Client1'),(2,'Linked2','Client1');

CREATE TABLE ProfileFan(Id int, LinkedInProfileId int, FanId int);

INSERT INTO ProfileFan VALUES (1111,1,17111),(1112,2,17111),(1113,1,17112);

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @columns1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 'LinkedInProfile' + CAST(LinkedInProfileId AS VARCHAR) FROM ProfileFan
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM ProfileFan;

SELECT @columns1 = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + '[LinkedInProfile' + CAST(LinkedInProfileId AS VARCHAR) + ']' FROM ProfileFan
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM ProfileFan;



SET @sql = 'SELECT Name, Info,' + @columns + ' FROM
(
  SELECT CONCAT(lip.Name,''('',pf.Id,'')'') AS val, f.Name as ''Name'', f.Info as ''Info'' , CONCAT(''LinkedInProfile'',pf.LinkedInProfileId) as LipId 
  FROM Fan f
  LEFT JOIN
  ProfileFan pf
  ON
  f.FanId = pf.FanId
  LEFT JOIN
  LinkedInProfile lip
  ON
  pf.LinkedInProfileId = lip.LiId

) AS src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(src.val) FOR src.LipId IN ('+ @columns1
  + ')
) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

This dynamic query of @sql will give output as:

```
SELECT Name, Info, LinkedInProfile1, LinkedInProfile2 FROM
(
  SELECT CONCAT(lip.Name,'(',pf.Id,')') AS val, f.Name as 'Name', f.Info as 'Info', CONCAT('LinkedInProfile',pf.LinkedInProfileId) as LipId 
  FROM Fan f
  LEFT JOIN
  ProfileFan pf
  ON
  f.FanId = pf.FanId
  LEFT JOIN
  LinkedInProfile lip
  ON
  pf.LinkedInProfileId = lip.LiId

) AS src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(src.val) FOR src.LipId IN ([LinkedInProfile1],[LinkedInProfile2])
) AS p;
```

Resultset:

```
    Name    Info    LinkedInProfile1    LinkedInProfile2
1   Fan1    Info1   Linked1(1111)   Linked2(1112)
2   Fan2    Info2   Linked1(1113)   NULL
```

Comment: `Name Info LinkedInProfile1 LinkedInProfile2
Fan1 Info1 Linked1(1111) Linked2(1112)
Fan2 Info2 Linked1(1113) Linked2(1114)` But I shoud be getting this In LinkedInProfile Column Linked1 instead of Linked2. Can you please update your query i dont know where i am missing it?

Comment: I have updated it now. There was a small mistake in the left join condition. You can find the simulation here as well: https://rextester.com/ZQNQK96212

Comment: Please see this link for an extension of this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516285/pivot-with-dynamic-columns-and-joins-5-tables)